# ViewPager2: Listen for setCurrentItem() completion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I recently upgraded my app to use ViewPager2.

When the user taps the finish-early button I call this code.

```
setCurrentItem(myLastPageIndex, false)
doSomeWork()
```

The `doSomeWork()` function enables the circular progress bar on the last page.

The thing is that when I call `doSomeWork()` the page isn't displayed yet and I get an exception because I'm trying to update a View that doesn't exist yet, `createFragment()` is called after `doSomeWork()`

This used to work perfectly with the old ViewPager, is there any way to know when the  `setCurrentItem(myLastPageIndex, false)` transition finishes?

I thought about using `OnPageChangeCallback`, however, I don't want `doSomeWork()` to be called when the last page is selected by the user, but only when I change the position page dynamically.

Comment: Is there a reason why that last page isn't controlling its own circular progress bar? It *is* the one who owns that view.

Comment: The last page has a finish button that calls `doSomeWork()` and handles everything on its own, however, if the time runs out, I need to force this behavior manually

Comment: I can't even use `onPageSelected` because it is called before `createFragment()` and before the fragment is displayed

Comment: You may trigger some listener callback in `onResume` of the PageFragment; which calls `doSomeWork()` on the parent fragment only if it is the last page and if it's scrolled dynamically

Comment: It is almost as if you shouldn't be reaching in to touch a fragment's views from outside of it. Why exactly do you need to do that, instead of having the Fragment reach *up* and observe whether its progress bar needs to be shown (or better, yet, `doSomeWork()` itself)?